# cofinite topology

Tags: general-topology

If we have topological space $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the co finite topology. If we have finite subsets in consideration they are definitely closed because open sets are of the form complement of finite set.

If we have infinite or finite subsets of real line in consideration how to look at their compactness and connectedness?

Comment: You don't have to look at the real line specifically. If a space has the cofinite topology, then it's compact. If the space is infinite, then it's also connected. Try to prove this.

Comment: It's confusing (and, strictly speaking, actually, wrong) to say "If we have topological space $\Bbb R$ equipped with the cofinite topology". No — it's just the **set** $\Bbb R$, which is given a topology other than "the usual topology".

Comment: @BrianO I completely agree with your point. A non empty set when equipped with a topology is called a topological space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be a set and equip it with the cofinite topology. Let $Y$ be a non-empty subset of $X$. We want to show that the relative topology on $Y$ is again the cofinite topology.

An open set in $Y$ has the form $V=U\cap Y$, where $U$ is open in $X$; then
$$
Y\setminus V=Y\cap V^c=Y\cap(U\cap Y)^c=
Y\cap(U^c\cup Y^c)=Y\cap U^c
$$
(where $A^c$ means the complement of $A$ in $X$). Since $U^c$ is closed in the cofinite topology (in $X$), either $U^c=X$ or $U^c$ is finite. Therefore $Y\setminus V$ is either $Y$ or it is finite.

Since $Y\ne\emptyset$ has the cofinite topology, it is compact. Take an open cover, choose a non-empty element and what's missing from it is closed, so it is covered by a finite number of open sets in the cover.

If it is infinite it is also connected: if $Y=A\cup B$, with $A$ and $B$ open and disjoint, one of them must be empty, because they are also closed.

Comment: for connectedness  of a inifinite subset we have have to show there does not exists any two non empty open and disjoint sets such that their union is equal to that of the infinite set  and you are trying to discard such a possibilty but i can't completely get it.

Comment: @User23 Open and disjoint is the same as closed and disjoint, if the union is the whole space. Said i In other terms, in an infinite set with the cofinite topology only the empty set and the whole space are open and closed sets.

Comment: while showing the set to be compact we choose an open cover and try to show it has a finite subcover. Where are you trying to choose a non empty element and how you proceed further?

Comment: @User23 Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover; take $U_0\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $U_0$ is not empty; then $X\setminus U_0=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ is finite (because it's a proper closed subset). Take $U_i\in\mathcal{U}$ with $x_i\in U_i$ (for $i=1,2,\dots,n$).

Comment: Thanks! Now I get your reasoning. I am just confirming if what I have under stood is correct. According to me in this case the subcover of the open cover $\mathcal {U}$ has $ n+1$ elements, that is, $ \mathcal{U}_0, \mathcal{U}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{U}_n$. which altogether completely covers the full subset $Y$ where  $ \mathcal{U}_1, \ldots, \mathcal{U}_n$ have one element each?

Comment: @User23 That is correct